# Reference/proof request: Prove that Hodge Operator can be defined by demanding $\omega\wedge*\eta=\langle\omega,\eta\rangle\mathrm{d}V_g$

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Unfortunately, John Lee leaves it as an exercise to prove that the Hodge operator can be defined by $\omega\wedge*\eta=\langle\omega,\eta\rangle\mathrm{d}V_g$, where $\mathrm{d}V_g$ is the Riemannian volume form.

I searched for a proof online (and in Tu's books), but it seems like most courses on Differential geometry (DG) don't cover the Hodge operator. A proof or a reference that covers the Hodge Operator would be much appreciated. Since I am beginner in DG, I'd like to have a very detailed reference, similar to John Lee's books.

Comment: How does Lee define the Hodge star? The expression you've written is by far the most common definition.

Comment: @Kajelad That's his definition. He says that the Hodge operator can be defined like that and leaves it as an exercise to prove that.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Lee's definition of the Hodge star, if $\eta$ is a $k-$form  $\star \eta$ is defined to be the unique $n-k$ form which satisfies 

$$\omega\wedge \star \eta = \langle \omega , \eta \rangle dV_g$$

You should show that this form is unique, Lee walks you through the proof of this I would highly recommend doing this exercise.

Comment: Two years have passed and now I can answer my own question: The proof can be found in the book [Mathematics for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/physics/mathematical-methods/mathematics-physicists-introductory-concepts-and-methods?format=HB) by Jan von Delft and Alexander Altland. Maybe I will write an answer with the full proof.